# Cant parse multipart response on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, mime, xcode5.1

I am implementing an application where i have to fetch data from server through web services. I am done with web service integration where i'm getting multipart response, which contains data for music files(.mp3 or .mid), images and plain texts. I followed this stack overflow [Parse multipart response for image download in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22095186/parse-multipart-response-for-image-download-in-ios?lq=1) reference.

Problem is while i am saving the data into corresponding file formate(mentioned in headers), it's became corrupted.I am using NSASCIIStringEncoding during data conversion first time and NSUTF8StringEncoding encoding to save data. I have saved the response [data here](https://copy.com/ZwmN1AynSF6p) in text file.

Please help me solving this problem.

thanks in advance :)