# NSData Multi-part response from NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, nsdata, postman

I need to make a web service call which returns an IMAGE in multipart/related response (Response I have pasted below after the code.)

I am not able to read the image data. Please help.
I AM ABLE TO get the response on POSTMAN. But no clue how to parse that in code.
ALSO, I need help in converting NSData into JSON or NSDictionary so that I can read the image data. I tried NSJSONSerialization, but it is returning NULL.

- CODE I HAVE WRITTEN :

  ```
  NSURL *url = [URIStringsClass messageAttachmentURI];  // Gets me our organization URI
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  NSURLResponse *response = nil;
  NSError *error = nil;

  // These are the headers that we need to set as per WebServices team documentation
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
  [request setValue:self.message.system forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-systemID"];
  [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.message.messageId] forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-messageID"];
  [request setValue: [[[_message attachments] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row] - 2]JSONStringForKey:@"name"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-attachmentID"];

  // I AM NOT SURE IF I HAVE TO MENTION THIS    
  //    [request setValue:@"multipart/related" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
  NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

  if(data != nil)
  {
      UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 200, 200)];
      UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 200, 200)];
      imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
      aView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
      [aView addSubview:imageView];
      [self.subjectView addSubview:aView];

      NSString *newStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];
      NSLog(@"JSON Data : %@", newStr);
  }
  ```
- `NSURLResponse` after executing the code

  ```
  (lldb) po response
  <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7c9965f0> { URL: https://............ } { status code: 200, headers {
      Connection = "keep-alive";
      "Content-Language" = "en-US";
      "Content-Length" = 64159;
      "Content-Type" = "multipart/related; boundary=\"MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_53A435D3A5CC74CCF71420587543829\"; type=\"text/xml\"; start=\"<0.urn:uuid:53A435D3A5CC74CCF71420587543830@apache.org>\"";
      Date = "Tue, 06 Jan 2015 23:28:56 GMT";
      Server = "WebSphere Application Server/7.0";
      "Set-Cookie" = "BIGipServerebiz-isqa-9444=1574180012.58404.0000; path=/";
      Via = Gateway;
      "X-Archived-Client-IP" = "127.0.0.1";
      "X-Backside-Transport" = "OK OK,OK OK";
      "X-Client-IP" = ".................";
      "X-CorrelationID" = "Id-54ac6fb500dfd23a00002862f08e4067 0; Id-54ac6fb50028d4fe000024d97aae61c6 0";
  } }
  ```
- Webservices response on POSTMAN :

  ```
  --MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_53A435D3A5CC74CCF71420585641061
  Content-ID: <0.urn:uuid:53A435D3A5CC74CCF71420585641062@apache.org>
  Content-Type: application/json;
      charset="utf-8"

  {"GetAttachmentResponse":{"executionContext":null,"attachment":{"attachInfo":{"name":4,"attachmentID":"0","mimiType":"application/octet-stream"},"attachRef":"cid:urn:uuid:53A435D3A5CC74CCF71420585641037@apache.org"}}}
  --MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_53A435D3A5CC74CCF71420585641061
  Content-ID: <urn:uuid:53A435D3A5CC74CCF71420585641037@apache.org>
  Content-Type: application/octet-stream

  ????JFIFHH??@ICC_PROFILE0ADBEmntrRGB XYZ ?acspAPPLnone???-ADBE

  [rest of binary data snipped out of question: see hex below or look at revision history]

  --MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_53A435D3A5CC74CCF71420585641061--
  ```

  In case anyone wants to see pretty version of JSON, it was:

  ```
  {
      "GetAttachmentResponse": {
          "executionContext": null,
          "attachment": {
              "attachInfo": {
                  "name": 4,
                  "attachmentID": "0",
                  "mimiType": "application/octet-stream"
              },
              "attachRef": "cid:urn:uuid:53A435D3A5CC74CCF71420585641037@apache.org"
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- `NSData` that I got from code:

  ```
  2015-01-06 14:56:53.682 KPFlagshipMessages[10676:147391] DATA : <0d0a0d0a 2d2d4d49 4d45426f 756e6461 72797572 6e5f7575 69645f35 33413433 35443341 
  35434337 34434346 37313432 30353835 36313938 34340d0a 436f6e74 656e742d 49443a20 3c302e75 726e3a75 
  7569643a 35334134 33354433 41354343 37344343 46373134 32303538 35363139 38343640 61706163 68652e6f 
  72673e0d 0a436f6e 74656e74 2d547970 653a2061 70706c69 63617469 6f6e2f6a 736f6e3b 0d0a0963 68617273 
  65743d22 7574662d 38220d0a 0d0a7b22 47657441 74746163 686d656e 74526573 706f6e73 65223a7b 22657865 
  63757469 6f6e436f 6e746578 74223a6e 756c6c2c 22617474 6163686d 656e7422 3a7b2261 74746163 68496e66 
  6f223a7b 226e616d 65223a22 494d475f 30313534 222c2261 74746163 686d656e 74494422 3a223022 2c226d69 
  6d695479 7065223a 22617070 6c696361 74696f6e 2f6f6374 65742d73 74726561 6d227d2c 22617474 61636852 
  6566223a 22636964 3a75726e 3a757569 643a3533 41343335 44334135 43433734 43434637 31343230 35383536 
  31393831 39406170 61636865 2e6f7267 227d7d7d 0d0a2d2d 4d494d45 426f756e 64617279 75726e5f 75756964 
  5f353341 34333544 33413543 43373443 43463731 34323035 38353631 39383434 0d0a436f 6e74656e 742d4944 
  3a203c75 726e3a75 7569643a 35334134 33354433 41354343 37344343 46373134 32303538 35363139 38313940 
  61706163 68652e6f 72673e0d 0a436f6e 74656e74 2d547970 653a2061 70706c69 63617469 6f6e2f6f 63746574 
  2d737472 65616d0d 0a0d0aff d8ffe000 104a4649 46000101 01006000 600000ff db004300 01010101 01010101 
  01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 
  01010101 01010101 01010101 ffdb0043 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 
  01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01010101 01ffc000 1108014d 
  00fa0301 22000211 01031101 ffc4001f 00000105 01010101 01010000 00000000 00000102 03040506 0708090a 
  0bffc400 b5100002 01030302 04030505 04040000 017d0102 03000411 05122131 41061351 61072271 14328191 
  a1082342 b1c11552 d1f02433 62728209 0a161718 191a2526 2728292a 34353637 38393a43 44454647 48494a53 
  54555657 58595a63 64656667 68696a73 74757677 78797a83 84858687 88898a92 93949596 9798999a a2a3a4a5 
  a6a7a8a9 aab2b3b4 b5b6b7b8 b9bac2c3 c4c5c6c7 c8c9cad2 d3d4d5d6 d7d8d9da e1e2e3e4 e5e6e7e8 e9eaf1f2 
  f3f4f5f6 f7f8f9fa ffc4001f 01000301 01010101 01010101 00000000 00000102 03040506 0708090a 0bffc400 
  b5110002 01020404 03040705 04040001 02770001 02031104 05213106 12415107 61711322 32810814 4291a1b1 
  c1092333 52f01562 72d10a16 2434e125 f1171819 1a262728 292a3536 3738393a 43444546 4748494a 53545556 
  5758595a 63646566 6768696a 73747576 7778797a 82838485 86878889 8a929394 95969798 999aa2a3 a4a5a6a7 
  a8a9aab2 b3b4b5b6 b7b8b9ba c2c3c4c5 c6c7c8c9 cad2d3d4 d5d6d7d8 d9dae2e3 e4e5e6e7 e8e9eaf2 f3f4f5f6 
  f7f8f9fa ffda000c 03010002 11031100 3f00fb87 e19fc3ff 00829a4f c1df851a af887e1a fc15d3a0 93e12fc3 
  39eeb53d 6be1f7c3 cb749649 7c0da13c b733dedf 6880bcd2 c8c6599e 579269a4 767625dd b3e63e32 f8d3fb19 
  f84a2b98 2cbe1cfc 2df1b6a5 047238b2 f0c7c22f 024b6ecc 8c5407d5 af3c3b65 a6471b31 00b4335e 328da180 
  e2bf1b34 ff0089cb aaf83fc0 52789bc5 3ab7886f a0f01782 ada26bfb bbbd5e6b 4860f0e6 94915bda da38992d 
  aded2183 ecf12430 a46a170c bbc2b1c9 b9f88b71 >
  ```

Comment: By the way, do not use `sendSynchronousRequest` from the main thread. Use any of the many asynchronous techniques, such as `NSURLConnection` `sendAsynchronousRequest` or `NSURLSession` `dataWithRequest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like very plausible multipart response, I see what appears to be a valid JPEG (or at least the start of one) in the second part. This is extremely unusual to see multipart responses: We construct multipart *requests* in our iOS code all the time, but we don't handle multipart *responses,* generally.

Your Objective-C code, though is trying to load this as an image, and it's not a simple image. You actually have to parse the multipart response.

Before we drag you through the weeds of the ugly process of parsing this multipart response, are you stuck with this sort of response? I'd much rather see a simple JSON response with the image base-64 encoded. Or a JSON response with a URL for the image which can be downloaded separately.

It's going to take a lot of ugly code to parse this non-standard response, so the question is whether there's any chance to change the response.

---

It sounds like you're stuck with this format. In that case, to parse this response, you first have to get the `boundary` out of the `Content-Type` in the `NSURLResponse` headers. Then you can scan the `NSData` response payload for `--` followed by that boundary string. Then you're going to have a couple of headers for each part, followed by a blank line, followed by the payload. The first payload is the JSON. The second is the image. You simple read in the bytes until you encounter the next `\r\n` followed by `--`, followed by the boundary. The whole thing is terminated with a `--` followed by a boundary, followed immediately by another `--`.

---

For discussions on how multipart responses are constructed see the discussion of [multipart responses](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html) in RFC 1341 (the MIME spec). Or see [RFC 2388](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt) (the multipart request created by HTML forms). Or see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24252378/1271826) of how to *create* a multipart request in Objective-C. Or just google "create multipart request". Once you get your arms around how multipart responses are created, then the parsing of the multipart response will be fairly intuitive. But definitely make sure you grok multipart payloads before going too much further.

See [Parse multipart response for image download in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22095186/1271826) for some promising Objective-C code for parsing these sorts of responses.

Comment: Hi Rob. Thanks for the response and editing the post. I am stuck with this kind of response.  We get JSON response exactly as shown in the question. Can you please help?

Comment: Well, the problem is that you don't just have a nice JSON response. Nor do you have a nice image. You've got both jammed together in a multipart response, which is going to be a pain to parse. Not difficult, just annoying. You're going to have to enumerate through the `bytes` of the `NSData`, parsing it as I've alluded to in my revised answer.

Comment: I was able to delete the headers and get the image data. But when I make UIImage out of that NSData, its returning nil.  May I please know what can I do?   Or, if I can give you the data, would you be able to tell me at what index exactly the image data starts and what encoding I have to use?

Comment: The first two bytes in this particular JPEG start with FF D8. And it goes up to (but not including) the subsequent 0D 0A 2D 2D followed by the boundary string. Note, in general, you cannot just look for FF D8, nor can you use the same index, nor can you hardcode boundary string to search for. You have to parse the multipart, hence that other answer referred you to. (I can't vouch for it, but strikes me as a place to start if you don't want to write your own parser). But if you want to upload this some place (full request headers details plus full payload, preferably as hex string), feel free.

Comment: I was able to make a generic parser (will share code soon). But when I encode the NSData into string to read the headers, I think it is corrupting the ImageData which is part of NSData that I am parsing. Can you please tell me how can I pass my raw data to you?

Comment: Just upload it somewhere (e.g. dropbox). Or create a hex string representation of it and share it on one of the code snippet tools such as gist.github.com or pastie.org.

Comment: I am able to parse and get the image. :)  But I am handling it a bit different. Will pass you the code soon Rob.  Thank you!

Comment: @StackOverFlowUserID I have the same problem as you. Could you please help me with the parsing code for multipart response?